# I need to write a file using java

Tags: java, makefile

this is my code

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package namereader;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 *
 * @author jpowell1225
 */
public class NameReader {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // TODO code application logic here
        boolean onoff = true;
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        String first = null;
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("txt",true);
       
        String last = null;
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        scan.useDelimiter(" ");
        //scan.useDelimiter();
        while(onoff){
            first = scan.nextLine();
         
            if(first.equals("quit")){
                    break;
                }
            
       
                
                fw.write(first);
                FileReader fr = new FileReader("txt");
                Scanner src = new Scanner(fr);
                count = first.lastIndexOf(" "); 
                count2 =first.indexOf(" ", 2);
                System.out.println("Your name is: " + first.substring(count) + " " + first.substring(count2, count2+2) + ". " + first.substring(0, count2));
 
        }
        fw.close();
        scan.close();
        
         
    }
    
}
```

While it does correctly output inputted name (switching it from First Middle Last to Last First Middle Initial), and it does correctly create a file named "txt", whenever I open the file it is empty.

I need to be able to add multiple inputs into the file "txt". TIA

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `flush()` the output stream as this

```
fw.flush();//flush it before close it.
fw.close();
```

Also you may use `try(<<Closable>>){}` and let Java closes(`FileWriter`) it automatically.

**EDIT**
`try(<<closable_0>>;<<closable_1>>;...){}` is a new scheme since java1.7 and it's used for let jvm automatically closes the `closable` object just after the block. in you code it could be like this.

```
try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("txt",true);){
//using the objects
}//jre will closes both :scan and :fw objects automatically
```

Comment: using fw.flush() didn't do anything for me, but could you show me how to format my code in a way to where I can use try{} (I am a newb at this :P)